# How to draw tiles on a Java Android game and store each tile into an array?

Tags: java, android, arrays

I'm trying to design an Android game based on tiles.

How would I go about making the background tile-like using `Bitmaps`? As in, making it have 5 columns by 3 rows, and then store each tile into an array? I want it be the full screen, except for the little space near the bottom wall of the screen (I'll have that be the options).

I know that I have to make a draw method, like so:

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas) {

}
```

and have it be rendered into my MainGamePanel, but how would I go about completing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: One thing I've tried is to make an array of type int, like: 

private int ar[][] = new int [3][5]; and then have 2 for loops looping through each row and column. After that, I'm lost because I haven't really experimented with bitmaps and canvases all that much

Comment: so the drawing works so far?

Comment: Nope, I don't know what to do when it comes to bitmaps and canvases. I've been trying to do canvas.drawBitmap(); but I don't know what to add into that.

Comment: I want to make the tiles something like what Plants Vs. Zombies have.